# Irreducibility of $p^{n-1}X^n+pX+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I am attempting to show that $f(X)=p^{n-1}X^n+pX+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for any positive integer $n$ and any prime $p$. At the behest of my teacher, and their hint, I would like to do so using Eisenstein's criterion on $p f(X)$, but I am having issues seeing how Eisenstein's is applicable here since $p$ will then be dividing the leading coefficient of $pf(X)$.

Comment: $pf(X) = g(pX)$ for $g(X)=X^n+pX+p$.

Comment: I should've seen that earlier ... But thank you so much!

Comment: Please delete the question since it is a dupe with no novelty.

Answer (score 2):

By the comment of [lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf) we have that $g(X)=X^n+pX+p$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion, and $g(pX)=pf(X)$.